# Adding dotted lines for signatures in a table

Tags: tables

I need to add dotted lines to 3 cells in a latex table with the lines being able to fill the cell depending on its width.

The table is the following

```
\documentclass{article}[10pt]

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.15\textwidth} p{0.25\textwidth}}
         \toprule
            & \makecell[lt]{\textbf{Ort}} & \makecell[lt]{\textbf{Datum}} & \makecell[lt]{\textbf{Unterschrift} \\ \textbf{(Projektverantwortliche)}} \\
         \midrule 
         \textbf{Der Projektverfasser} &  &  &  \\
         \makecell[lt]{Address \\ 
         Address \\
         Address \\
         Address
         } & & & \\
         \textit{Projektleiter} & Dotted Line & Dotted Line & Dotted Line   \\
         \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\dotfill` does the job:

```
\documentclass{article}[10pt]

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.15\textwidth} p{0.25\textwidth}}
         \toprule
            & \makecell[lt]{\textbf{Ort}} & \makecell[lt]{\textbf{Datum}} & \makecell[lt]{\textbf{Unterschrift} \\ \textbf{(Projektverantwortliche)}} \\
         \midrule
         \textbf{Der Projektverfasser} &  &  &  \\
         \makecell[lt]{Address \\
         Address \\
         Address \\
         Address
         } & & & \\
         \textit{Projektleiter} & \dotfill & \dotfill & \dotfill  \\
         \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```